# In an article talking about Chinese cuisine, what does 辉煌 describe in 以至辉煌至今?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This article is talking about Chinese cuisine.

中国的饮食文化历经数千年，
Chinese cuisine is thousands of years old,
始终具有魅力，
it is always charming,
是因为它不仅民族特性鲜明，
not only because of its distinct ethnic characteristics,
而且善于吸收不同国家、不同区域、不同民族的优异之处，
but also because it was good at absorbing different nations', regions' and ethnicities' culinary fortés,

以至辉煌至今。
1. which (ability to absorb) is still true today.
2. this (ability to absorb) still shines through today.
3. it (Chinese cuisine) is still splendid today.

什么事情，事物是‘辉煌的‘？这里‘辉煌’的形容词描述了什么？

可以简述为：‘中国饮食以至辉煌至今。’吗？

为‘辉煌’我有：杰出的; 灿烂的

Comment: 可以简述为：“中国的饮食文化辉煌至今。"

Comment: I don't think it is a well written sentence. Just like 中国的饮食文化辉煌灿烂 not a good express。

Answer (score 3):

辉:

(n) brightness; splendour; radiance

(v) to shine

煌:  splendid; brilliant; sparkling

辉煌 means ' to shine brilliantly'

Most of the time, 辉煌 is used as a compound, acting as an adjective for: "splendid; glorious; brilliant".

> 什么事情，事物是‘辉煌的‘？这里‘辉煌’的形容词描述了什么？

'辉煌' is an adjective when it is placed before a noun. For example: 'brilliant battle record' (辉煌战绩).

> '中国饮食辉煌至今' - 
>   "Chinese cuisine is still shining brilliantly till today"

In this context, 辉煌 is either acting as a verb phrase: 'shine brilliantly'. In which, 辉 is acting as a verb: 'to shine';

Or the sentence just omitted the verb: 'still be' (仍是)

'中国饮食(仍是)辉煌至今' -- 'Chinese cuisine (is still) glorious till today"

look at 'splendid battle record' (辉煌战绩) again,  辉煌 is clearly an adjective because it is placed before the noun 战绩.

However, in '战绩辉煌', 辉煌 could also be treated as a verb phrase (battle record shines brilliantly) with 战绩 as the subject.

Or 辉煌 is still an adjective, with the verb omitted in the phrase:  '战绩(非常)辉煌'--  'battle record (is very) splendid'

> 为‘辉煌’

If you want to say: 'for glory', 辉煌 is not the word, because it is not a noun.

'For glory' in Chinese is '为荣耀'

Answer (score 3):

Q1 什么事情，事物是‘辉煌的‘？这里‘辉煌’的形容词描述了什么？
A: 辉煌的 describe中国的饮食文化。

Q2 可以简述为：‘中国饮食以至辉煌至今。’吗？
A:No. It miss a reason. Seem to be "Chinese cuisine cause brilliant untill now. "

Correct answer(both are correct)

1
中国饮食 add reason ,以至辉煌至今

For example

（main clause）
中国的饮食文化历经数千年，
Chinese cuisine is thousands of years old,

(describe)
始终具有魅力，
it is always charming,

(reason)
是因为它不仅民族特性鲜明，
not only because of its distinct ethnic characteristics,

(reason)
而且善于吸收不同国家、不同区域、不同民族的优异之处，
but also because it was good at absorbing different nations', regions' and ethnicities' culinary fortés,

（result）
以至辉煌至今

2中国饮食辉煌至今 is no grammar mistake, but is seem no mention of the next sentence.